# Connections to SQL Server Files (*.mdf) require SQL Server Express 2005 to function properly

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am trying to add new existing item .mdf database file created in SQL Server Express 2008 R2.

When I try that i got error "Connections to SQL Server Files (*.mdf) require SQL Server Express 2005 to function properly."

What I have to do?

Comment: have you tried google at least? :) Enter error message and you will get lots of results with that error.

Comment: Guys, if a machine already has the licenced version of SQL Server, why in the world Visual Studio needs SQL Express? does it make any sense? I am still stuck on this crap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

[Jon Gallant's Blog: Solution to the exception: "Connections to SQL Server files (*.mdf) require SQL Server Express 2005 to function properly."](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jongallant/archive/2010/01/12/solution-to-the-exception-connections-to-sql-server-files-mdf-require-sql-server-express-2005-to-function-properly.aspx)

Otherwise, these may also help:

1. [ASP.NET: Connections to SQL Server files [...]](http://forums.asp.net/t/1120411.aspx/1?connection%20to%20SQL%20Server%20files%20mdf%20require%20SQL%20server%20express%202005%20to%20function%20properly%20);
2. [Predicate: Connections to SQL Server files (*.mdf) [...]](http://predicatet.blogspot.com/2007/01/connections-to-sql-server-files-mdf.html).

I do hope this helps! =)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio 2010, Change the Sql Server Instance Name as follows:

`Tools` > `Options` > `DataBase tools` > `Data Connection` > `Sql Server Instance Name as blank`